# What is this treatment on the walls of my basement?

Tags: basement, construction, materials

[image: flaking wall covering near door]

[image: harder, more permanent covering throughout the rest of the basement]

I'm wondering what this covering is on the walls in my unfinished basement? Most of it is pretty hard and rigid, though there is some near an exterior door that's flaking off. This mottled texture and discoloration is pretty consistent throughout the entire basement. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like stucco or something similar? (Quoting Groucho:  "You can get any kind of house you want. You can even get stucco...  oh, how you can get stucco.")

Comment: @keshlam is there any reason why it would look this atrocious? Is it an aesthetic sort of treatment? It baffles me and I think it's quite ugly and annoying, but I just want to make sure I know enough about it as possible before working more on the basement and its walls.

Comment: I haven't seen stucco indoors and it isn't one of my favorite wall treatments outdoors, so I'm just guessing. Yes, stucco  is often a deliberately rough texture. It's possible that someone was doing this to try to make the wall less porous, or they thought whatever's behind it was uglier... Plaster over the inside of brick foundations used to be common, but that was usually smooth.

Comment: FWIW, I'd have asked about that during pre-purchase inspection.

Comment: If the seller didn't disclose the water infiltration issues they appear to have tried to cover up, NOW is the time to bring it up. The statute of limitations on failure to disclose is usually short - two years in my state.

Answer (score 3):

It is a textured covering. Easy way to cover the unfinished block or concrete walls, usually concrete blocks. It's just a very easy and quick way to cover the concrete blocks at a lower expense. It is usually actually concrete.

It is flaking because the concrete blocks absorb moisture and cause the covering to come loose.